# Visual Basic loop sum of integers ^ 2 till user input. power of 2

Tags: vb.net, loops

I need help with one simple task:

Input an integer number **n** and output the sum: 1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + **n**^2. Use input validation for **n** to be positive.
My code does not work and till now is:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim inputNumber As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive number.")
    inputNumber = Console.ReadLine()
    If inputNumber <= 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Please use only positive numbers > 0 !")
    End If
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For i = 1 To i <= inputNumber
        sum = sum + (i * i)
        i = i + 1
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(sum)

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain "does not work". Do you get an error message? Does it provide wrong results? Also, rethink your tags. I doubt this is VBA. VB6? VB.NET?

Comment: Not the question, but (sum of squares from 1 to n) = n^3 / 3 + n^2 / 2 + n / 6. Ref: [Series - Sum of the Squares of the First n Natural Numbers](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these changes:

```
Dim inputNumber as Long  ' not Integer.  Also change sum, i.
...
inputNumber = CLng(Console.ReadLine)    ' make it a number, not a string
...
Dim sum as Long   ' yum
dim i as Long     ' don't assign it here
for i = 1 to inputNumber  ' don't use "<=" in a for loop
    ...
    ' i = i+1    ' Don't increment i within the loop, since the loop does that for you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim Input As Integer
Input = TextBox1.Text

```
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0


    Dim x As Integer
    x = 0

    Dim y As Integer
    y = 0

    For a = 1 To Input
        y = Math.Pow(a, (Input - i))
        x = Math.Pow(a, (Input - i)) + x
        i = i + 1
    Next

    Label1.Text = x
End Sub
```